# Wordpress, disable profile meta data?

Tags: wordpress, meta

When editing a user through Admin, the meta data are displaying at the bottom of the profile like this: https://prnt.sc/1013lu0

I remember that I activated it somehow but I don't seem to find how to disable it. I haven't installed any plugins that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the WooCommerce Store Toolkit plugin that caused this.